# registration page gives an error in php in xampp control panel v3.1.0.3.1.0

Tags: php, xampp

```
<?php
require 'core.inc.php';
require 'connect.inc.php';
if(!loggedin()){
  if(
     isset($_POST['username']) &&
     isset($_POST['password']) &&
     isset($_POST['password_again']) &&
     isset($_POST['firstname']) &&
     isset($_POST['surname'])
  ){
     $username       = $_POST['username'];
     $password       = $_POST['password'];
     $password_hash  = md5($password);
     $password_again = $_POST['password_again'];
     $firstname      = $_POST['firstname'];
     $surname        = $_POST['surname'];
         if(
            !empty ($username) &&
            !empty ($password) &&
            !empty ($password_again) &&
            !empty ($firstname) &&
            !empty ($surname)
         ){
              if($password == $password_again){
                $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
                $query_run = mysql_query($query);
                  if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)==1){
                    echo 'Sorry..! This user name '.$username.' already exist.<br/>  <br>Pleasetry with any other.';
                  }else{
                    $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$username', '$password_hash','$firstname', '$surname')";

                      if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
                        header('Location: register_success.php');
                      }
                  }
              }else{
                echo 'Password is not matching.<br> Please enter again same password.'
              }
         }else{
           echo 'All fields are required. Thanks';
         }
  }
?>
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Username:<br>   <input type ="text" name="username" value = "<?php echo $username; ?>"><br><br>
Password:<br>   <input type ="password" name="password"><br><br>
Password Again: <br> <input type="password" name="password_again"><br><br>
First Name:<br> <input type="text" name="firstname" value = "<?php echo $firstname; ?>"><br/><br>
Sur Name:<br>   <input type="text" name="surname" value = "<?php echo $surname; ?>"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Register" >
</form>
<?php
}else if(loggedin()){
  echo 'You\'re logged in.';
}
?>
```

**I get these errors:Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in C:\xampp\htdocs\core.inc.php on line 5**

     Undefined variable: username in **C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php** on line **46**
    
**Notice**:  Undefined variable: firstname in **C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php** on line **49**
    
**Notice**:  Undefined variable: surname in **C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php** on line **50**

Comment: `Undefined variable` error are so realistic :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The HTTP Referer is a client-controlled value, your error means that your browser didn't set it.
2. In `register.php`, at line 46, you are using a variable named `username` that you didn't define
3. Same as point 2, at `register.php`, line 49
4. Same as point 3, at `register.php`, line 50

Comment: Do yo mean that the browser doesn't support the http referer  variable?.I am a noob at php. Can you please suggest a solution ?

Comment: I mean that your browser didn't set it. To avoid this you can use a session variable (i.e. `$_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER']`) and update it in every page using `$_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`